# psql: fatal database does not exist error

Tags: postgresql

I have a linux user account, postgresql role, and associated database, all called foo.

from the linux user foo, I ran the command

```
dropdb foo
```

Now when I try to run psql from the linux user foo, I get the error...

```
psql: FATAL:  database "foo" does not exist
```

So does this mean that when running psql from a linux user account, there must be a database associated with that linux user account?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) assumes that you want to connect to a database, you can either provide one (just after the command) or it will assume you want to connect to a database whose name is the same as your username (or the account name of the process that started `psql`):

So, you could write:

```
psql my_db
```

or

```
psql -d my_db
```

or yet

```
psql --dbname=my_db
```

... and `psql` will connect to the (local) database named `my_db`.

You have more connection options that you can check in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING).

If you don't have yet a database created, check [`createdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-createdb.html).